# Do I need to define a table variable in MSQL stored procudre if I want to call a stored procedure from excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I try to call a stored procedure from excel 2007 by VBA. I would like get return from stored procedure into excel sheet. But I get the 'run-time 3074 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed' on Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset.

I do a lot of search without conclusion. I just want to know whether I need to define a table variable first in MSSQL stored procedure, then insert into it.

below is the codes I write:

******** Stored procedure sp_weekly **********

```
select [field1], [field2] into mytable_2 from mytable_1

select a.*, b.field4 from mytable_2 a
inner mytable_3 b on join a.field1 = b.field3
```

---

*********** in excel Marcos

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenConnection()

Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim CommandText As String

Set objMyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset



ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=abcsql,1433;Initial Catalog=admin;User Id=sa;Password=1234abcd;"
objMyConn.Open ConnectionString


Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
CommandText = "exec [admin].[dbo].[sp_weekly]"
objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
objMyRecordset.Open 

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

end
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error as the query is returning no results. To execute the stored proc, you need to do something like:

```
Sub PullFromStoredProc()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open _
            "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
            "Data Source=abcsql,1433;" & _
            "Initial Catalog=admin;" & _
            "User Id=sa;" & _
            "Password=1234abcd;"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "[admin].[dbo].[sp_weekly]"
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    Set rs = .Execute
End With

Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs


rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. But it does not want again. same error message. I do debug and find out when the execution passes 'end with, , all values inside the with statement are released.

Comment: after execute 'end with' , .ActiveConnection becomes <object variable or with block variable not set>

Comment: The code is fine, but your stored proc is wrong. Have you tried running it in SQL server studio directly? The syntax is all wrong for your join, have a look here [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Sorry about it. That is an example. I did not check it properly. it is only idea that I make two select statement in my procedures. the real stored procedure did work properly